# Expandable Listview with icons for parent and child

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create an expandable listview similar to the expandable list shown [here](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://blogimg.chinaunix.net/blog/upfile2/100902103610.jpg&imgrefurl=http://blog.chinaunix.net/u3/118340/showart_2316211.html&h=450&w=306&sz=35&tbnid=cPbVCb2O8UfoNM%3a&tbnh=127&tbnw=86&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dexpandablelistview&zoom=1&q=expandablelistview&usg=__CHWBwdQ5oHx6KYBKd38RU3--yg8=&sa=X&ei=OlTtTL2TFoSqvQPDwcH-AQ&ved=0CCwQ9QEwBA)

Are there any examples which would help me achieve this.

Thr parent and child data I have would be static always.

I use [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html) as my reference. Can any expert kindly guide me as to what code snippet I need to add to this, so that I can set icons for both parent and child.

Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example that you say you use as a reference there is a class called `ExpandableListAdapter`.  You need to make your own class that extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and use that to create the entries in your list.  The two methods you will need to focus on to change the layout of the entries are:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

In both of these in the example they call `getGenericView()` which just returns a `TextView`, but you can do anything you want.  You can inflate an xml layout or just build one in code right there and return it.  It's really no different than using a normal `ListAdapter`.

If you want to override the default expanded indicator you can create your own stateful drawable like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_expanded="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/expander_ic_maximized" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/expander_ic_minimized" />
</selector>
```

and put that where ever you want in your layout and give it the id of `@android:id/groupIndicator`.  I think that should work.  Let me know what you find.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot for the reply. I am going to try this out now.

Also, can you please say, how I can change the position of expand/collapse button from extreme left to extreme right.